# Sharing variable around different instances of YUI

Tags: module, yui3, instances

I have made up the custom module as :

```
YUI.add('util', function(Y) {
   Y.namespace('com.myCompany');
   var NS = Y.com.myCompany;
        NS.val = undefined;
}, '3.3.0', {
   requires : []
});
```

What I am trying to do is share this variable val in the instances where I use this module "util". As in

```
YUI().use("util","node","event",function (Y) {
    Y.namespace('com.myCompany');
    var MV = Y.com.myCompany;
    var setVal = function(e){
        MV.val = 10;
}
   Y.on("click", setVal,"#one");
  });
```

Now if I want to get this in other instance I am doing as the following:

```
 YUI().use("util","node","event",function (Y) {
        Y.namespace('com.myCompany');
        var MV = Y.com.myCompany;
        var getVal = function(e){
            alert(MV.val);
        }
       Y.on("click", getVal,"#two");
    });
```

But this does not seem to be working. Is there a way to get this behavior. I am doing this only to split up the code.

Comment: Do you need the separate sandboxes or are you only doing that to split up the code?

Comment: just doing it to split up the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you should only create *one* sandbox.  The correct way to break up your code is to use [`YUI.add`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/YUI.html#method_add) to create the modules and specify their dependencies.  One way to do this is to structure your code as follows:

```
// util.js
YUI.add('util', function (Y) {
    var NS = Y.namespace('com.MyCompany'); 
    NS.val = null;
}, 'version', {
    requires: ['some', 'dependencies']
});

// one.js
YUI.add('one', function (Y) {
    var NS = Y.namespace('com.MyCompany');
    Y.on('click', function (e) { NS.val = 23; }, '#one');
}, 'version', {
    requires: ['util']
});

// two.js
YUI.add('two', function (Y) {
    var NS = Y.namespace('com.MyCompany');
    Y.on('click', function (e) { alert(NS.val); }, '#two');
}, 'version', {
    requires: ['util']
});

// index.html
<button id="one">Set the value</button>
<button id="two">Get the value</button>

<script>
    YUI.use('one, 'two', 'node', 'event', function (Y) {
        // main application logic here
    });
</script>
```

This allows you to break up your code into separate modules that share the same YUI sandbox instance.

Note also [`YUI.namespace`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/YUI.html#method_namespace) returns the namespace in question, so you don't need the extra variables.

Comment: You can also share certain data (or communicate) between YUI instances with Y.Global see: http://andrewwooldridge.com/blog/2011/03/08/cross-yui-communication-and-custom-events/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that YUI() is creating a new sandbox with each execution.  If you want to reuse it you need to capture its value after the first "use" execution and reuse that value later.  There may be a better YUish way to do this but I use a global YUI_MAIN:

```
var YUI_MAIN = YUI().use("util","node","event",function (Y) {
  Y.namespace('com.myCompany');
  var MV = Y.com.myCompany;
  var setVal = function(e){
    MV.val = 10;
  };
  Y.on("click", setVal,"#one");
});

YUI_MAIN.use(function (Y) {
  Y.namespace('com.myCompany');
  var MV = Y.com.myCompany;
  var getVal = function(e){
    alert(MV.val);
  };
  Y.on("click", getVal,"#two");
});
```

If you really wanted to share between separate sandboxes and avoid an extra global you could use a closure to create a private variable with something like this:

```
YUI.add('util', (function () {
  var privateUtilNS = {};
  return function(Y) {
    privateUtilNS['val'] = undefined;
    Y.setVal = function(e){
      privateUtilNS.val = 10;
    };
    Y.getVal = function(e){
      alert(privateUtilNS.val);
    };
  };
  }()), '3.3.0', {
    requires : []
});

YUI().use("util","node","event",function (Y) {
  Y.on("click", Y.setVal,"#one");
});

YUI().use("util","node","event",function (Y) {
  Y.on("click", Y.getVal,"#two");
});
```